# Creating chloropleth for particular state from shape file of India

Tags: python, shapefile, geopandas

There are shape files available for India wit each district. I would like to create a chloropleth for Bihar alone. But I do not know how to select individual districts from the chloropleth map of India. Any help would be really appreciated.

This is my code so far :

```py
import pandas as pd
import os
import geopandas as gpd

aoi_bihar = gpd.read_file(
  os.path.join('Districts-Census-2011', '2011_Dist.shp'))
aoi_bihar.plot(figsize=(50,50))
```

**Data :** [Link to drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1WSxdmqXNtZd8BZay5Wpl4TUclTVqqsln?usp=sharing)

**Current output :**

[image: Current output]

**Desired output :**

Displaying the state of Bihar alone along with it's districts.

Comment: `aoi_bihar = gpd.read_file('2011_Dist.shp',rows=slice(100,300))` This slice allows us to extract the relevant districts, so if we give you a list of Bihar districts, we may be able to achieve this!

Comment: Thanks man, will try it out.